# How do I continue with next element in the Java Stream in case of exception?

Tags: java, spring

I have a stream like this,

```
List<String> test = Arrays.asList("1", "2,", "3");

test.stream().map(t -> {
  try {
    validate(t);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, e.getMessage(), e);
  }

  return true;
})
```

In case of an exception, I would like to store it somewhere, process the next element and then show all exceptions at once. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, don't rethrow the exception:

```
var exceptions = test.stream().map(t -> {
    try {
      validate(t);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return e;
    }

    return null;
  })
    .filter(Objects::nonNull) // if you don't need to preserve the index
    .toList();
```

Comment: I'd add `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` before the `toList() `.

Comment: Is there a good way to then display all exceptions as a response in a readable way with 500 response?

Comment: @Lewis12 What's readable is subjective – and not the job of the API.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code slightly.  Your main issue is that you're re-throwing that exception when you catch it -- that will stop processing at the first exception.  Then you need some way to store the inputs that cause an error (that's what `invalidInputs` is for.  I'm assuming that your next step is to actually use the results of that input to convert, otherwise you don't need to use `map()`, so my "validate" method also just does the conversion too.  I use a JUnit test harness for stuff like this, and I left in the `assert()`s; you should take them (and the `@Test` annotation) out for your code.

```
    //throws NumberFormatException if input doesn't parse into an integer
public static Integer validate(String input) throws Exception{
    return Integer.parseInt(input);
}

@Test 
public void testStreamMap() {
    List<String> test = Arrays.asList("1", "2,", "3");
    List<String> invalidInputs = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> result= test.stream().map(t -> {
        Integer localResult;
      try {
        localResult=validate(t);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        invalidInputs.add(t);
        localResult=null;
      }
      return localResult;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    assertTrue(invalidInputs.contains("2,"));
    assertFalse(result.contains(2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*You can try this approach to **collect all the exceptions in a list** as follows:*

*Here,*

I have iterated over the list using `forEach` and in case of `catch` , added the exception `e` in the `listOfExceptions` list.

- As I have entered three invalid inputs in the list , it is giving three exceptions in the list at the end corresponding to each element which is giving exception.
- **For the demo purpose**, I have created one more list `listOfElementsWithoutExceptions` showing the elements which are processed without any exceptions.

**Note:** *You can have your own custom exception list in place of `List<Exception>`.*

```
public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> test = Arrays.asList("test1", "test2", "3","4","test5","6");

        List<Exception> listOfExceptions = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> listOfElementsWithoutExceptions = new ArrayList<>();
        test.forEach(t -> {
            try {
                validate(t);
                listOfElementsWithoutExceptions.add(t);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                listOfExceptions.add(e);
            }
        });
        System.out.println("list of exceptions:: " + listOfExceptions);
        System.out.println("list of elements without exceptions:: "+ listOfElementsWithoutExceptions);
    }

    private static void validate(String t) {
        Integer.parseInt(t);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
list of exceptions::

[java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "test1", 
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "test2", 
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "test5"]

list of elements without exceptions:: [3, 4, 6]
```